# systemd path doesn't trigger service (anymore) when file is overwritten by renaming another file

Tags: systemd

I have a setting in which a `systemd.path` unit watches a particular file:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Watch config file for changes

[Path]
PathChanged=/path/to/my/config.file

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

where the `.service` specification has the same file name save for the extension.

- Until `systemd 239-68.0.2`, creating a temporary copy of `config.file`, modifying it, and renaming (`mv`) it back to `config.file` would trigger the `.service`.
- With `systemd 239-74.0.1`, it no longer does. I have to explicitly open it in an editor (e.g. `nano`), but then the service is already triggered *when I open the file, not only upon saving or closing*. What *does* work is overwriting the file by copying (`cp`) the temporary file back to `config.file`.
- The behavior is the same regardless of using `PathChanged` or `PathModified`.
- `touch`ing the file to update the timestamps doesn't trigger the service either.

Is this change in the behavior intentional? How can I get back to the "old" behavior - which I prefer, because usually a script performs multiple changes to `config.file`, and I don't want to have the service triggered on every single modification.

Copying (`cp`) and deleting the temporary file "manually" is of course an option, but would require changes at multiple locations that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: It looks like you have a difference in behavior with a simple reproducer. Have you consisted opening [an issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues)?